# ng-click does not modify array

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-directive

I have a problem with an old AngularJS APP where I have to manage selection.

basically I am trying to modify the array of `selectedItems` with `ng-click`

but it does not react to changes to the array, it firs with logs but not when I want to splice or push.

Any idea why this might happen?

`  
Categories/Subcategories







{{ category.category.name }}

```
                <div ng-repeat="subcategory in category.sub_categories">
                  <md-option
                    ng-value="subcategory.id"
                    class="subcategory-name"
                    ng-click="productCtrl.toggleSelection(category.category.id, subcategory.id)"
                  >
                    {{subcategory.name}}
                  </md-option>
                </div>
              </div>
            </md-optgroup>
          </md-select>
        </md-input-container>`
```

I really would like to keep this as `ng-click` because of simplicity.

Behind the hood I have a toggle function where I manage the selection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share also some javascript code?

Comment: Hey! The task itself was a bit complex - I had a large array returned from the backend and the point was to manage parent-child relationship within cat-sub_cat. I changed my approach - I used the array just the display the selected items, but the state itself - I did it with object to avoid repeated loops.It's a really disorganised angular code with 3000 lines on code in one file. 
It worked well and instead of using ng-click - I used ng-change. which also had some downside - because it detect the change too early on a first load in my web page and I had to manage the fetch just to load once.